# $q promises - Object is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I wanted to run the promises sample from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q, here is my Code:

```
angular.module('testControllers').controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {

    function asyncGreet(name) {
        // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (true) {
                    resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
                } else {
                    reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
    promise.then(function(greeting) {
        console.log('Success: ' + greeting);
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
}
```

Chrome keeps telling me:
TypeError: object is not a function

What did I do wrong with the sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you using angularjs in version 1.3 at least please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.ver = angular.version.full;

  $scope.message = ""

  $scope.asyncGreet  = function (name) {
    // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (true) {
          resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
        } else {
          reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
        }
      }, 1500);
    });
  }

  promise =  $scope.asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
  promise.then(function(greeting) {
   alert('Success: ' + greeting);
  }, function(reason) {
    alert('Failed: ' + reason);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    Angular ver: {{ver}} 






  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: version 1.3 was the problem, I had 1.2!

Answer (score -2):

Please see example below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.test = true;

  function asyncGreet(name, test) {
    // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.

    var deffered = $q.defer();


    setTimeout(function() {
      if (test) {

        deffered.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');

      } else {
        deffered.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
      }
    }, 1000);

    return deffered.promise;

  }

  $scope.action = function() {

    var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood', $scope.test);
    promise.then(function(greeting) {
      alert('Success: ' + greeting);
    }, function(reason) {
      alert('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
  };

  $scope.action();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="test" ng-value="true" ng-change="action()" />TRUE
    <input type="radio" ng-model="test" ng-value="false" ng-change="action()" />FALSE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is about using $q as a constructor, not in the CommonJS implementation.   The code snippet the OP posted is directly out of the docs.