# $q is not a function : angulargrid.js

Tags: angularjs

Im using [this](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/angulargrid/index.html#documentation) angular library to view the images like in pinterest.

It has this set of code in it.

```
function ngCheckAnim() {
   var leavingElm = domToAry(listElms).filter(function(elm) {
        return single(elm).hasClass('ng-leave');
        });
   return $q(function(resolve) {
        if (!leavingElm.length) {
            resolve();
        } else {
          single(leavingElm[0]).one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
         $timeout(function() {
             listElms = getListElms();
             resolve();
         });
         });
        }
      }); 
}
```

While using the library, im gettin the error **$q is not a function at ngCheckAnim**.

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Have you injected '$q' service in your controller ?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati Yes. I did that

Comment: Can you post code of your controller...mainly the injection statements

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati app.controller('AssetsCtrl', ['pics', 'angularGridInstance', '$q', function (pics, angularGridInstance, $q)

Answer (score 0):

$q got it own constructor from angularjs 1.3 onwards. But you can change the code and use normal approach as mentioned in answer below.

[$q promises - Object is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380554/q-promises-object-is-not-a-function/26380675#26380675)

Specifically for angulargrid.js I made some changes at two places.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
                img.onload = function() {
                    onLoad(img);
                    deferred.resolve();
                  };
                  img.onerror = deferred.reject;

              loadedImgPromises.push(deferred.promise);
```

Another place.

```
if (!leavingElm.length) {
              deferred.resolve();
            } else {
              single(leavingElm[0]).one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  listElms = getListElms();
                  deferred.resolve();
                });
              });
            }
          return deferred.promise;
```